# jQuery show div on top of other divs upon hover

Tags: jquery, css

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="btn">
        <div id="reveal">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="btn2">
        <div id="reveal2">
        </div>
    </div>
    <style>
        #btn, #btn2
        {
            background-color: red;
            height: 100px;
            width: 200px;
        }
        #btn2
        {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        #reveal, #reveal2
        {
            background-color: green;
            height: 400px;
            width: 200px;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#btn').hover(function () {
            $('#reveal', this).stop(true, true).slideDown("normal");
        }, function () {
            $('#reveal', this).stop(true, true).hide();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've got a wall of tabs on a web page and I when a user rolls over one I want a div to slide over the same tab that was rolled over and any tabs that are positioned below.

If you run my demo code you can see the that the div being revealed goes behind the div further down the page.

Is it possible to get this to work?

Also, is it bad to be having an inner div be taller than its container?

One other thing I tried to do was put the inner div outside on its own and then absolutely position it such that it appears over the button.

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
```

This results in an unfortunate effect whereby the btn div keeps re-triggering the animation. It does fix the issue with the levels though.

Comment: yes it is bad .. what how can a child be elder then parent. Illogical.

Comment: So else can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `position:relative` to the `btn` and `reveal` elements and add a `z-index:999` to the `reveal` elements.

Also better to use classes for elements with common styling and behavior..

**Html**

```
<div class="btn">
    <div class="reveal"></div>
</div>
<div class="btn">
    <div class="reveal"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.reveal {
    background-color: green;
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    display: none;
    z-index:999;
    position:relative;
}
```

and **jquery**

```
    $('.btn').hover(function () {
        $('.reveal', this).stop(true, true).slideDown("normal");
    }, function () {
        $('.reveal', this).stop(true, true).hide();
    });
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/T7USy/

Comment: The problem I have now is that when doing this in my actual website, the reveal jumps when its slid down beyond the height of its container. So the animation only half works.

Comment: @IanWarburton,  can you post a link to the actual website ?

Comment: Soz... its not on the internet! I've just made it fade in instead instead of sliding down.

Comment: Ahh... fixed it. My reveal div was inheriting a fixed height.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QWE6x/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="btn">
        <div id="reveal">1111111111</div>
    </div>
    <div id="btn2">
        <div id="reveal2">222222222</div>
    </div>
    <style>
        #btn, #btn2 {
            background-color: red;
            height: 100px;
            width: 200px;
            position:relative;
            z-index:3;
        }
        #btn2 {
            margin-top: 10px;
            z-index:1;
        }
        #reveal, #reveal2 {
            background-color: green;
            height: 400px;
            width: 200px;
            display: none;
            position:absolute; /*<--update it*/
            left:0;            /*<--update it*/
            top:0;             /*<--update it*/
            z-index:2;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('[id^=btn]').hover(function() {
            $('[id^="reveal"]', this).stop(true, true).slideDown("normal");
        }, function() {
            $('[id^="reveal"]', this).stop(true, true).hide();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: The problem I have now is that when doing this in my actual website, the reveal jumps when its slid down beyond the height of its container. So the animation only half works.

Comment: Yes fully expanded but only the bit inside of the container animates. Once it reached the end it snaps to fully open.

Comment: No it didn't help. I'm using a fade in instead for now.

Comment: Ahh... fixed it. My reveal div was inheriting a fixed height.